# How to update D-Bus on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dbus, qdbus

I'm looking for a simple way to update or to install **D-Bus** 1.6 or higher version on **Ubuntu 12.04**.

When I install d-bus 1.8 package from the following link, unfortunately Ubuntu does not start again after reboot.

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/dbus.html

- Is there a simple way to install newer version on Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Why specifically do you want to update dbus?

Comment: I'm searching for the same… I need to update in order to compile applications that use bluetooth and C++11. Refer to this bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701220 As referred on http://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/NEWS?h=dbus-1.8, this problems where solved on version 1.5.

Comment: I'm also trying to upgrade D-Bus on Ubuntu 12.04 as it is a dependency of the latest version of blueZ.  I also experienced the problem where Ubuntu won't boot after upgrading with the steps in that guide.  I'm wondering if you ever found a solution for this.